# Filter by terms in an array

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to filter by terms within an array on elasticsearch documents. This is what the documents look like:

```
{
    "name": "Foo",
    "id": 10,
    "industries": ["Tech", "Fashion"],
    ...
}
```

But for the various filter-based queries I try, I've gotten zero results. e.g.:

```
$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_search?pretty=true' -d '
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "terms": {
                            "industries": ["Tech"],
                            "execution": "or"
                        }
                    }]
                }
            },
            "query": {"match_all": {}}
        }
    },
    "from": 0,
    "size": 20
}
'
```

I've tried about a dozen different queries against various simplifications and filter clauses, e.g. here's a simplified one:

```
$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_search?pretty=true' -d '
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "terms": {
                    "industries": ["Tech"],
                    "execution": "or"
                }
            }
        }

    },
    "from": 0,
    "size": 20
}
'
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What analyzer are you using for the industries field? If you are using the default, it will actually lower case and split your stings, which would explain why your filters aren't picking those documents up (e.g., it's looking for "Tech" when only "tech" exists). If you set the mapping to `not_analyzed` (or use the [`multi fields`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/_multi_fields.html) option), that might solve your problem.

Comment: Yep, that did it. Thanks Chris! If you make it an answer I can accept it.

Comment: Just did - thanks! Glad that solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What analyzer are you using for the industries field? If you are using the default, it will actually lower case and split your stings, which would explain why your filters aren't picking those documents up (e.g., it's looking for "Tech" when only "tech" exists). If you set the mapping to not_analyzed (or use the multi fields option), that might solve your problem.